# How do I use WinWait on multiple labels without blocking the others?

Tags: autohotkey

I have `SetTimers` pointing to multiple labels but they stop working when I have a `WinWait` in one of the labels.

```
SetTimer, MyLoop, -5
SetTimer, MyLabel, -1000
Return

MyLoop:
    SoundBeep, 700
    SetTimer, MyLoop, -5
Return

MyLabel:
    SoundBeep, 300
    WinWait, Notepad
    SetTimer, MyLabel, -1000
Return
```

`MyLoop` stops working as soon as `MyLabel` reaches the `WinWait` section. How do I make `MyLoop` continue on while `MyLabel` is waiting for the `WinWait` on its own?

Comment: Check if the window exists in a loop with `sleep 20` inside.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the docs: [Threads](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm), [SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm), [WinWait](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm)

```
i := 0
settimer, afterTenMsg, 1000 ; Start our timer!
GoSub, WaitForNotepad 
ExitApp

WaitForNotepad:
    WinWait, Untitled - Notepad ; This Thread is interupted by the Timer.
    MsgBox % "Yeah NotePad Opened!" ; Close this will return to line 3
return

afterTenMsg:
    i++
    if (i == 10) {
        settimer, afterTenMsg, off
        run, notepad.exe
        settimer, openMsgBox, 1000 ; Interupt MsgBox thread after 1 sec
    }
return ; Returns to WinWait

openMsgBox:
    settimer, openMsgBox, off
    MsgBox % "We interupted a MsgBox!" ; close this will return to line 8
return
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to use `WinWait` instead of a pseudo loop to optimize the resource consumption of the script.

Comment: I updated my example using WinWait to show it can be interrupted with SetTimer. The comments added are there for reference of where the code will Return to when the thread is complete. Hopefully you can get a better understanding out of this. I really suggest you read all three of the links I posted, as I didn't show every case or example. For instance, you can prioritize Timers, and even set Subroutines/Functions as uninterruptible, this information is contained in the docs.